# Ist this set closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $D$ be the set such defined by the inequalities:

$$
x \geq 0 \\
y \geq 1 \\
xy - 16 = 0
$$

$x$ and $y$ here belong to $\mathbb{R}$.

I wonder if this set is closed.
I tried to prove it is not closed by coming up with a sequence s.t. the convergence point is not in the set. I tried this sequence, but it obviously does not work, because it does not converge.
$$
(16/y, y)
$$

On the other hand, it seems to me that for any $x_1$, there will always be $x_2$ such that $x_2 < x_1$, which would make the feasible set not closed from an intuitive point of view.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This set is indeed closed: hint: if $x_n \to x_0$ and $x_n \ge 0$, is $x_0 \ge 0$? If also $y_n\to y_0$, is $x_n y_n \to x_0 y_0$?

Comment: If $f_1(x,y)=x, f_2(x,y)=y, f_3(x,y)=xy,$ then all three are continuous and your set is $$f_1^{-1}([0,\infty))\cap f_2^{-1}([1,\infty))\cap f_3^{-1}(\{16\}),$$ which is the intersection of three closed sets, so is closed.

Comment: This definitely makes sense, @ThomasAndrews. And of course, the set would not be closed in case $x > 0$ instead of $x \geq 0$. Thanks.

Comment: It actually is closed when $x>0,$ but only because there are no values with $x=0$ when $xy-16=0$ @DunhoClark

Comment: Basically, with $x>0,$ the topology proof doesn’t work directly, But since $f_3^{-1}(\{16\})\cap f_1^{-1}(\{0\})=\emptyset,$ then $$f_1^{-1}((0,\infty))\cap f_3^{-1}(\{16\}= f_1^{-1}([0,\infty))\cap f_3^{-1}(\{16\}$$

Comment: Also, of course, $xy-16=0$ and $y\geq 1>0$ means $x>0.$ So the $x\geq 0$ condition adds nothing new.

Comment: The "=" in all inequalitiess should make it clear that this set is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We’ll use:

> let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. If a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then when $C\subset Y$ is closed, then $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X.$

If $X=\mathbb R^2,Y=\mathbb R,$ then take the three continuous functions: $$\begin{align}f(x,y)&=x\\g(x,y)&=y\\h(x,y)&=xy 
\end{align} $$

Then your set can be written as $$D=f^{-1}([0,\infty))\cap g^{-1}([1,\infty))\cap h^{-1}(\{16\})$$

Since $[0,\infty), [1,\infty),\{16\}$ are closed in $\mathbb R,$ this means $D$ is the intersection of three closed sets in $\mathbb R^2,$ and hence $D$ is closed.

---

It is true that $D$ contains $(x_n,y_n)$ with $x_n>0$ and $x_n\to 0.$ But $y_n=16/x_n$ does not converge, so $(x_n,y_n)$ does not converge, so it doesn’t disprove that $D$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this set is closed. To prove this you might consider: The set is a intersection of the sets given by $\{(x,y):x\geq 0\} = [0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$, $\{(x,y):y\geq 1\} = \mathbb R\times[1,\infty)$ and $\{(x,y):xy=16\}$, which is the graph of the function $x=16/y$.

The first two sets are clearly closed (by sequence definition of closedness and product metric). For the last one consider: If $(x_n,y_n)$ is a sequence in this graph with $y\geq 1$ that converges to some $(x,y)$. Then $x_n = 16/y_n$. Note that if $y\geq 1$ then this function is continuous, so if $x_n\to x$ then also $y=\lim y_n= 16/x$. Thus the limit is in the set.

Intersections of closed sets are closed.